# How to search entity in an given knowledge graph with multiple ttl files locally?

Tags: python, sparql, ttl, rdflib, knowledge-graph

I am now trying to query the knowledge graph in local. The knowledge graph is the [CORD-19 Annotated By SemRep](https://research.bioinformatics.udel.edu/covid19kg/rdfdumps), which is a `tar.gz` file after downloading. I want to search if the entity or relation exists in the knowledge graph or not.

## Expected Result

Something like:

```
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["entity_text", "preferred_name", "semantic_type", "semantic_type_name", "count"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "entity_text": { "type": "literal", "value": "COVID-19" } , "preferred_name": { "type": "literal", "value": "COVID-19" }  , "semantic_type": { "type": "literal", "value": "dsyn" }   , "semantic_type_name": { "type": "literal", "value": "Disease or Syndrome" }   , "count": { "type": "typed-literal", "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer", "value": "602476" }} ] } }
```

SPARQL

```
###########
# CSQ4: Top Entities of CORD-19 Dataset Annotated by SemRep
# Author: Chuming Chen (chenc@udel.edu)
###########
PREFIX cord19: <https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/covid19/cord19#>
PREFIX semrep: <https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?entity_text ?preferred_name ?semantic_type ?semantic_type_name  (COUNT(concat(?entity_text,?preferred_name, ?semantic_type, ?semantic_type_name )) AS ?count)
FROM <https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/covid19/cord19>
WHERE
{
    [
        cord19:_id ?doc_id ;
        cord19:annotations
        [
             cord19:entity
            [
                a semrep:Entity ;
                cord19:semantic_type ?Semantic_type ;
                cord19:entity_text  ?entity_text ;
                cord19:preferred_name  ?preferred_name ;
            ]
        ]
    ] .
    ?Semantic_type a semrep:SemanticType .
    ?Semantic_type rdfs:label ?semantic_type.
    ?Semantic_type rdfs:comment ?semantic_type_name.  
}
GROUP BY ?entity_text ?semantic_type  ?semantic_type_name ?preferred_name
ORDER BY DESC(?count)
LIMIT 50
```

## What I want to achieve using API

Now I use the given api and the SPARQL to search the entity in kg. I can get results but it was too slow. That's why I want to try it locally.

```
import requests
headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+json',
        }       
        
query = '' # use the same query
data = {'query': query}
        
response = requests.post('https://sparql.proconsortium.org/virtuoso4/sparql', headers=headers, data=data)
```

## What I've tried

I have already extracted the compressed file. Inside the folder, there's a lot of `ttl` files. The file is downloaded from [here](https://research.bioinformatics.udel.edu/covid19kg/rdfdumps), the 7th row.

```
import tarfile
file = tarfile.open('cord19.rdf.tar.gz', 'r:gz')
file.extractall('foldername')
file.close()
```

I tried to parse the `ttl` files by `rdflib`

```
from rdflib import Graph
from glob import glob
filenames = glob("folder/*.ttl") # len(filenames) = 593241
g = Graph()
for filename in filenames[:2]:
  g.parse(filename, format = 'ttl')
```

I only tried to parse two files first. I use the query that is nearly the same as the previous one but just remove the `FROM` line.

```
###########
# CSQ4: Top Entities of CORD-19 Dataset Annotated by SemRep
# Author: Chuming Chen (chenc@udel.edu)
###########
PREFIX cord19: <https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/covid19/cord19#>
PREFIX semrep: <https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?entity_text ?preferred_name ?semantic_type ?semantic_type_name  (COUNT(concat(?entity_text,?preferred_name, ?semantic_type, ?semantic_type_name )) AS ?count)
#FROM <https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/covid19/cord19>
WHERE
{
    [
        cord19:_id ?doc_id ;
        cord19:annotations
        [
             cord19:entity
            [
                a semrep:Entity ;
                cord19:semantic_type ?Semantic_type ;
                cord19:entity_text  ?entity_text ;
                cord19:preferred_name  ?preferred_name ;
            ]
        ]
    ] .
    ?Semantic_type a semrep:SemanticType .
    ?Semantic_type rdfs:label ?semantic_type.
    ?Semantic_type rdfs:comment ?semantic_type_name.
  FILTER regex(?entity_text, "covid-19", "i").
}
GROUP BY ?entity_text ?semantic_type  ?semantic_type_name ?preferred_name
ORDER BY DESC(?count)
LIMIT 50
```

```
results = g.query(query)
```

There's no result in `results.bindings`.

### More Attempts

I tried to parse other links in `PREFIX`

```
from rdflib import Graph
from glob import glob
filenames = glob("folder/*.ttl")
g = Graph()
for filename in filenames[:2]:
  g.parse(filename, format = 'ttl')
g.parse("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
g.query(query) # empty result
```

```
from rdflib import Graph
from glob import glob
filenames = glob("folder/*.ttl")
g = Graph()
for filename in filenames[:2]:
  g.parse(filename, format = 'ttl')
g.parse("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
g.parse("https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/") # No plugin registered for (text/html, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>
```

## Repeat my question again

So far I can parse multiple files in `Graph` or `ConjunctiveGraph` function, but failed to get results. How can I successfully gain the local graph that can have results (by the query) that are not empty?

Meanwhile, if parsing through all the ttl files is the correct approach, the length of the filenames are super big (593241), and it takes a long time to parse. How to solve it? (this is the extended question only if the parsing through all the ttl files are neccessary)

Comment: Hi I am new to ask questions and not sure why others can edit my questions....but the kg is named CORD-19, not COVID-19. Not a typo.

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce this error. Works for me as expected besides the result being empty when just loading the first n files randomly. You have to at least force loading of the schema files, i.e. `semrep_model.ttl` and `semrep_semantic_types.ttl` otherwise the last triple patterns won't match

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for your comment. I tried once but it was supposed to gain results not empty, so I revise my question.

Comment: You are trying very complicated queries. If you are parsing files ok, can you get other, simpler, queries to run? I would start small and build up the query to get to what you want and that way find the problem.